# Internal Server Error when viewing disabled product (Enterprise)

Tags: magento-enterprise, fatal-error, enterprise-1.14

I'm running Enterprise 1.14.1 and have an issue with a "white screen", Internal Server Error whenever **viewing a disabled product with compilation enabled.**

If I disable compilation, and view the product, I see a 404 page as expected.

Unfortunately, I am not seeing any errors in my server log files either that would allow me to track down what's going on. I can replicate this both in the production environment and locally.  Developer mode is "On." Caching is disabled.  System and Exception logging are enabled.

### To Replicate

1. Enable Compilation
2. Disable a Product.
3. Clear Cache (if enabled)
4. View product.

### What I've Tried

I've tried uncommenting `#ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in the index.php file.  If I do this, I get a 200 response, but the error is not displayed on screen nor within the error logs.

I've obviously tried recompiling.

I'm going to start disabling Extensions one-by-one to see if there's some kind of conflict.

### Update

I was able to replicate this on a clean install of Enterprise with a single configurable product.

Comment: Have you already opened a support ticket with Magento?

Comment: @brentwpeterson Thanks - yes, just did. I'll post the answer here when it's resolved.

Comment: you need to find your error log.

Comment: @ADM - As stated, there are not any errors being output to my error log in this particular instance. Error settings in PHP are set to `E_ALL` and other Magento errors _are_ output to the log - just not in this case.

Comment: check your server configuration. if you get Internal Server Error, there must be something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three possible solutions:

1. Disable compilation :)
2. Rewrite `Mage_Catalog_ProductController` class and modify `viewAction()`
3. Modify `registerScope` method inside `Varien_Autoload` class

Code sample for method 2.

```
....
// Render page
try {
    $viewHelper->prepareAndRender($productId, $this, $params);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    if ($e->getCode() == $viewHelper->ERR_NO_PRODUCT_LOADED) {
        if (isset($_GET['store'])  && !$this->getResponse()->isRedirect()) {
            $this->_redirect('');
        } elseif (!$this->getResponse()->isRedirect()) {
            $this->_forward('noRoute', 'index', 'cms');
        }
    } else {
        Mage::logException($e);
        $this->_forward('noRoute', 'index', 'cms');
    }
}
....
```

Code sample for method 3.

```
static public function registerScope($code)
{
    self::$_scope = $code;
    if (defined('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH')) {
        @include_once COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . self::SCOPE_FILE_PREFIX.$code.'.php';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Reindex 'Em All - Very interesting.  I notice the major difference (at least for #2, which is the solution I used) is that we specify the controller and module arguments in the _forward function and that seems to take care of it. I'll have to dig into why that breaks when compilation is enabled... weird.

Comment: please explain the path of step 3.I don't get it

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution, the Magento Enterprise Dev Team has created a patch, `PATCH_SUPEE-5095_EE_1.14.1.0_v1.sh`. This employs "Reindex 'Em All's" solution #3 in patch form.

The patch is a one line change, which changes the following in `lib/Varien/Autoload.php` on line 105.

`@include COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . self::SCOPE_FILE_PREFIX.$code.'.php';`

#### to

`@include_once COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . self::SCOPE_FILE_PREFIX.$code.'.php';`

Comment: This bug exists in CE 1.9.1.1 also and the patch change above successfully fixes the problem - patch doesn't seem to be available to download for CE though :/